# How access node value in JavaScript data structure

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this JavaScript data structure in which I want to access node elements("one","two"). Here is what I have tried

```js
var myObj, x;

myObj = { 
  "one":{
    "name":"John",
    "age":30 
  },
  "two":{
    "name":"fgdf",
    "age":3543 
  }
};

for(var i in myObj) {
  var c = myObj[i];
  console.log(c.value);
}
```

**Expected output**

```
one
two
```

Comment: What is `QUESTION_MARKS`?

Comment: sorry updated now

Comment: Hi @Saurabh Kumar, you would also need to parse your JSON to be able to manipulate it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: please add the wanted result as well. btw, you have no [JSON](http://json.org/), because JSON is a string by definition.

Comment: @t3__rry : There is NO JSON in the question!

Comment: console.log(myObj.one); console.log(myObj.two) Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object#684692

Comment: @Quentin aha I need to wake up, sorry for the interference guys!!

Comment: `alert(c.value);` — Your properties are called `name` and `age` not `value`.

Comment: @Quentin i want "one" and "two" in alert

Comment: @SaurabhKumar — Then look at `i`!

Comment: myObj = { 
    "one":{
    "name":"John",
    "age":30 
    },
    "two":{
    "name":"fgdf",
    "age":3543 
    }

};
     for(var i in myObj){
     alert(i);
     }

Comment: @HousseinZouari thanks

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/EbgNFO0O8nu1Y1UuuV1R?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `JSON.stringify(c)` instead of `c.value`:

```js
var myObj, x;
myObj = {
  "one": {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30
  },
  "two": {
    "name": "fgdf",
    "age": 3543
  }

};
for (var i in myObj) {
  var c = myObj[i];
  alert(JSON.stringify(c));
}
```

Comment: i want "one" and "two" in alert

Comment: @SaurabhKumar updated the answer